# mysql: signal sqlstate to php

Tags: php, mysql

hi guys I am developing a php-mysql application. The mysql database uses triggers to enforce a variety of constraint. 
Let's say that there is a table that just have a two columns (ID and value) and a trigger prevents the insertion of negative values.
        CREATE TEABLE my_tbl (
        id INT(9) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMIRY KEY,
        value INT(9) 
        )
The trigger would look something like this:
        CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger` 
        BEFORE INSERT ON `my_tbl` 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
        IF NEW.value < 0 THEN
        SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'value must be positive';
        END IF;
        END

There are several triggers, each one has this line of code:
    SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'value must be positive';
the only thing that changes is the message_text, that depends on the violated constrain. If you I the mysql console to input date the triggers "show" me this description but when I use the php interface it just don't add the data and doesn't return any error, so the user don't have any clue that the data has not been inserted.
**MY QUESTION: Is there any way to display the message_text on the php-generated page?**
I've used the search function, but every solution I've found uses PDO and/or Object oriented php while I would like to stick with **procedural php and mysql**

Comment: This perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.sqlstate.php ?

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but I had already found that function, if I understand correctly it returns the five character code that identify the error, so in m example (that I cannot get to be displayed correctly formatted, sorry^^) it would return '45000' while I need 'value must be positive'

Comment: My bad, I did not scroll to the bottom of that page, you're right.

Comment: @DeDee did you find a solution to this question? Reading MESSAGE_TEXT in PHP?

Comment: @RehbanKhatri I'm afraid nope, I was not looking but if I had to, I'd fiddle with the range 45000 - 450FF and create the same error messages in both SQL and PHP, so both binaries would know what the number means.

I know that only 45000 is recommended for custom errors, but I doubt they'd reserve no wider space, i.e. 45000 - 4500F or 45000 - 450FF.

Comment: Sounds a good solution. The way I had to implement this was setting custom error number from withing stored procedure. So basically instead of setting `MESSAGE_TEXT` I set `MYSQL_ERRNO=2000`. I used 2000 and above error number because mysql has error numbers 1000 to 1700 reserved. Then in php I have constant mappings for error numbers and their error text. Not sure if this is right solution but is working for me right now

Comment: @RehbanKhatri,@DeDee, I had forgotten about this question, I have added the solution I used in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) function, it returns the last error meassage.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It shows recent error but not the error I gave in message_text